# Use jquery and ajax to search instagram api by tag

Tags: jquery, ajax

I want to be able to have users input a tag and see results of recent media pertaining to that tag.  I have tried this code but I'm getting an error in the Chrome Console.

"[https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags//media/recent?callback=jQuery224041941550…24017687.51352a5.571b3b1e6a9945eea4745b7bea5d38f2&count=10&_=1465951645890](https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags//media/recent?callback=jQuery224041941550%E2%80%A624017687.51352a5.571b3b1e6a9945eea4745b7bea5d38f2&count=10&_=1465951645890)"

```js
var token = '24017687.51352a5.571b3b1e6a9945eea4745b7bea5d38f2',
 num_photos = 10;
 var hashtag = $("input.form-control").val(); // hashtag without # symbol

 $(function() {
 "use strict";
 $('.input-group').on('submit', function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();

     $.ajax({
         url: 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/' + hashtag + '/media/recent',
         dataType: 'jsonp',
         type: 'GET',
         data: {
             access_token: token,
             count: num_photos
         },
         success: function(data) {
             console.log(data);
             for (x in data.data) {
                 $('.thumbnail').append('<img src="' + data.data[x].images.standard_resolution.url + '">');
             }
         },
         error: function(data) {
             console.log(data);
         }
     });
 });
 });
```

Comment: Whats the error you are getting in chrome console?

Comment: It's a 404 error attached to the URL mentioned in the original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the link you posted, it looks like `hashtag` is not being passed into the ajax request? Note there should be a string between `/tags/` and `/media/` in

`https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/NEED_HASHTAG_STRING_HERE/media/recent?callback=jQuery224041941550…24017687.51352a5.571b3b1e6a9945eea4745b7bea5d38f2&count=10&_=1465951645890`

After I added a hashtag in with the complete `access_token`:

`https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/plane/media/recent?access_token=24017687.51352a5.571b3b1e6a9945eea4745b7bea5d38f2`

I got:

`{"pagination": {"deprecation_warning": "next_max_id and min_id are deprecated for this endpoint; use min_tag_id and max_tag_id instead"}, "meta": {"code": 200}, "data": []}`

However, that's because the `hashtag` "plane" was not used in the last 20 photos of your Sandbox account. So try using a `hashtag` that you actually used recently.

In short, you needed to pass in the hashtag string with the `access_token`. I've only targeted the ajax side of things. You may also want to double check why your `hashtag` string is not being passed in or why `$("input.form-control").val()` is not being read, or anything related to your submit form.